# ng build --prod fails when sourceMap is true in angular.json

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

I am using angular 6 and angular-cli version 6.2.7.

When I perform a production build using ng build --prod with sourceMap: false in angular.json configuration there is no problem. But when I use sourceMap: true I get this error

[image]

Here are my other details

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can try specifying the max_old_space_size setting (in MB)

**`node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`**